# Create commandline tool NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, node-modules

I need to create a NodeJs tool for quickly connect and manage some API. I have already developed codes for authentication, get users and create new users.

This is my first experience with NodeJs and I couldn't find a quick guide to resolve some issues. One of my issues in this moment, is to make the values ​​parametric, such as username and password for authentication. Now i put thees values inside the code but i need to manage into a main module by commandline and send this data to other modules.

Can you recommend some modules that I can study to integrate these features? For example commander, inquirer or other. I don't know which one to choose to have a correct management of my modules.

Comment: I wrote this article about using javascript for the git hooks: https://medium.com/@Sergeon/using-javascript-in-your-git-hooks-f0ce09477334 . This ofc is unrelated but the article has a lot of stuff about cli and nodejs that may be useful for you. For cli apps I've always used inquirer and never missed anything in particular about inquirer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sergeon. I think I have solved at least a first problem. With this example code:

```
var request = require("request");
var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);

var username = myArgs[0];
var password = myArgs[1];

//var username = "mif4cc17ciul0"
//var password = "Tr0ppR03"

request.post({
        "headers": { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
        "url": "https://api.site.com/v1/token",
        "auth": {
            "user": username,
            "pass": password
        },
        "form": {
            "grant_type": "password",
            "username": "user_test",
            "password": "User-00",
            "scope": "6780f180-4ae5-8617-5d8t-f267f5045d4"
        },
    },
    function(err, response, body) {
        var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(body);
        if ("access_token" in jsonResponse) {
            global.mytoken=(jsonResponse.access_token);
            console.dir(mytoken);
        }
    }
);

module.exports = request
```

I request the token and manage to put at least the first two values ​​(eg: token.js username password) from the command line and does it work. It doesn't in a best way, but it's already a start. Next I will have to define the values ​​with which to pass the variables, through like inquirer module (eg: `node token.js -u username -p password`).

Anyway previously, if I'll want to create a main process to call this code. I think it can also help me to better manage inquirer module. So, how can I send the variables?

The final goal should be: `node main.js username password` or the best `node main.js -u username -p password`